# Why was my question deleted? complete-sql-standard-syntax-diagram

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions

I asked a question on SO and got a lot of negative feedback.  Then, after asking some questions, I revised the OP, and got a little bit of positive feedback.  After returning to the site a few hours later, my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13994780/complete-sql-standard-syntax-diagram) was deleted.

I'm quite confused at why my question was deleted, and I also still don't know the answer.  Could anyone shed any light on this?

Google's [cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:stackoverflow.com/questions/13994780/complete-sql-standard-syntax-diagram&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS502US502&oq=cache:stackoverflow.com/questions/13994780/complete-sql-standard-syntax-diagram&aqs=chrome.0.57j58j61j60l2.5475&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) may stay around for another few hours.

This cache, unfortunately, was taken before my edits.  Those appear to be irrevocably lost, with the constructive feedback and partial answers that I had received.

The OP: Where can I find a complete syntax diagram of the SQL standard?

Summary of the edits: After researching this for a couple days, I have found the technical documentation relatively impenetrable.  What I am really looking for is a syntax diagram that includes every syntactic construct, enough to write a parser; however, I would prefer the documentation to not have a lot of verbose explanation.

Comment: Also, if there is a way to retrieve my lost information, I would appreciate it.  I thought it was pretty rude that the little bit of help I got was deleted.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your question was *closed* because it's not considered a good, on-topic question for this site. There's a lot, a *lot*, of conversation covering closure over the years, but starting simple, quoting the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq):

> We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them, but if your question generally covers …
>
> - a specific programming problem
> - a software algorithm
> - software tools commonly used by programmers
> - practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

You appear to be asking for a specification document. That doesn't fit well in any of those categories. Stack Overflow loves to help with programming question, but it doesn't love to be a documentation repository. Your later edit was better, it provided the justification and background (*"I did my homework!"*), but that's not enough to overcome the non-topicality.

Your question was deleted, in all likelihood, because the three users who voted to delete it didn't think the question was likely to be made suitably on-topic to be answered. It was deleted relatively quickly, but nowhere near record time.

You asked for a copy; here you go.

> Where can I find a complete syntax diagram of the SQL standard?
>
> I have searched Google with the phrase "syntax diagram of the SQL standard", which yields either specific implementations (e.g. Oracle, SQLLite) or simplifications.  Being relatively new to whitepapers and such, I have found it quite difficult to navigate the technical documentation that I have found over the course of the last couple days of research.
>
> I already understand SQL; what I am really looking for is an offical RFC, etc. that gives enough information to write a parser for the syntax, without pages of verbose explanation to sift through.
>
> The link that Tomek posted is a good start, but it is still quite verbose, is out of date, and I don't understand why it is being hosted by Carnegie Mellon, as opposed to a standards body.  The link is [http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/%7Eshadow/sql/sql1992.txt)

I didn't see anything else in the comments that might have been helpful - you already included Tomek's comment in your edit.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation and for resurrecting my question.